# unknown column in On clause on simple mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

It is probably just too late, but I cant wrap my head around what is wrong

This is giving me an unknown column in ON clause error

```
SELECT *
FROM abstracts, parts
JOIN parts test ON abstracts.abstract_id = test.abstract_id
```

But this works perfectly

```
SELECT *
FROM abstracts, parts
WHERE abstracts.abstract_id = parts.abstract_id
```

It's a much bigger query, so I can't just use the working example.

Comment: The 2 queries you've given are different. They return different resultsets. How could you compare them?

Comment: See... it really is late. I don't see that.

Comment: @zerkms They are not different, the first one just has a typo.

Comment: @Ariel: they are different. The first query is a valid query with joining a cartesian product with another table.

Comment: @Adam Meyer: you don't see that there are 3 tables and 2 joins in the first table whereas only 2 tables and 1 join in the second?!

Comment: No, there are only 2 tables. test is just an alias for parts, not another table. Yes, as written it does look like 2 joins (i.e. a self join and a join to the second table), but it's clearly just a typo.

Comment: @zerkms I see 2 tables, one of them aliased to "test", and I was trying to do a single join. I normally join using the where statement like the second example, and think I am just very confused right about now. But Ariel's example does work.

Comment: @Ariel: I cannot predict that it **is** a typo. Currently they are both perfectly valid and different queries.

Comment: @Adam Meyer: there are 3 tables. Abstracts, parts and parts. The table part is used twice, but it is still yet another table used in joining. So there are 3 tables in the first query and 2 tables in the second. First query is a cartesian product + join, second is just a join. They are different.

Comment: @zerkms - It is times like this it becomes very clear that I went to design school. I need to go re-read my SQL book.

Comment: @zerkms I can assume it's a typo because the where clause does not do anything with the self join, and there is little reason to do that, especially not a beginner. Beginners rarely do self joins in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT *
FROM abstracts, parts
JOIN parts test ON abstracts.abstract_id = test.abstract_id
```

Should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM abstracts JOIN parts
  ON abstracts.abstract_id = parts.abstract_id
```